# Awk for loop not searching all fields

Tags: for-loop, awk

I'm trying to

1. print the first 3 columns
2. find all fields with "Eury_gr1_" and print them to the 4th column
3. if there are no "Eury_gr1_" in the whole row print 0 in the 4th column.

Input looks like the below named "final_pcs_mod_test.csv":

```
PC_00001,143,143.0,Eury_gr2_(111),Eury_gr5_(19),Unk_unclust_(1),Eury_gr1_(6),MAV_eury_(6)
PC_00004,137,137.0,Eury_gr6_(20),Eury_gr11_(24),Eury_gr14_(24),Eury_gr8_(8),Eury_gr12_(13)
PC_00027,109,109.0,Eury_gr1_(80),MAV_eury_(8)
```

The desired output will look like the below named "eury1":

```
PC_00001,143,143.0,Eury_gr1_(6)
PC_00004,137,137.0,0
PC_00027,109,109.0,Eury_gr1_(80)
```

The command I'm using is:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","};{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^Eury_gr1_/){a=$i} else {a="0"}} print $1,$2,$3,a}' final_pcs_mod_test.csv > eury1
```

The actual output is:

```
PC_00001,143,143.0,0
PC_00004,137,137.0,0
PC_00027,109,109.0,Eury_gr1_(80)
```

As you can see the first row is missing a "Eury_gr1_" entry. Looks like the code is only looking in the first specified column and not searching all columns as I want. I've been messing around with `for(i=4;i<=4;i++)` etc... but so far cannot seem to get it to find entries in the last columns of the input. The whole input file has a max of 17 columns. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Output will be same as shown samples.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/Eury_gr1_\([0-9]+\)/){
        found=(found?found OFS:"")$i
     }
  }
  if(found==""){ $4="0"   }
  else         { $4=found }
  print $1,$2,$3,$4
  found=""
}' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(i<=3){
      val1=(val1?val1 OFS:"")$i
    }
    else if(i>3){
      if($i~/Eury_gr1_\([0-9]+\)/){
        found=(found?found OFS:"")$i
      }
    }
  }
  if(found==""){ $4="0"   }
  else         { $4=found }
  print val1,$4
  found=val1=""
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                    ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                   ##Starting BEGIN section from here of this program.
  FS=OFS=","                             ##Setting field separator and output field separator to comma here.
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                    ##Traversing through all the fields of current line here.
    if(i<=3){                            ##Checking condition if field number of lesser than or equal to 3 then do following.
      val1=(val1?val1 OFS:"")$i          ##Creating val1 and keep adding values there.
    }
    else if(i>3){                        ##else if field number is greater than 3 then do following.
      if($i~/Eury_gr1_\([0-9]+\)/){      ##Checking if current field is Eury_gr1_(digits) then do following.
        found=(found?found OFS:"")$i     ##Creating variable found and keep adding values there.
      }
    }
  }
  if(found==""){ $4="0"   }              ##Checking condition if found is NULL then make 4th field as zero.
  else         { $4=found }              ##else set found value to 4th field here.
  print val1,$4                          ##Printing val1 and 4th field here.
  found=val1=""                          ##Nullifying val1 and found here.
}' Input_file                            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

***OP's attempt fix:*** As per OP's comments fixing OP's attempt here. But this will match only 1 occurrence of `Eury_gr1` each line, for looking for all occurrences please refer my above solution.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
}
{
  for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/^Eury_gr1_\([0-9]+\)$/){ a1 }
  }
  print $1,$2,$3,a1
  a1=""
}' Input_file
```

Comment: Ah! It works like a dream! Thank you! Would you mind adding a litle explination as I'm very much in the learning stages with bash and could use the pointers for what I was doing wrong and how you fixed it?

Comment: @Dvik, Your welcome. I have added your attempt's fix also. Problem in your attempt was, you were using same variable in if and else condition so hence it was never able to catch the matched value, because each time a non matched field will come it will overwrite matched value in it. Cheers.

Comment: Perfect. Makes total sense, I see it now. Thanks again!